# R ggplot conditional color without exact match

Tags: r, colors, conditional-statements

I am trying to color points in a line conditional if they are above or below the yearly mean in `ggplot2` and I cannot find any help that where colors are not exactly matched to values.

I'm using the following code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = M, y = O)) + geom_line()
```

I want it to be one color if O is above mean(O) or below.

I tried to follow the advice but I just get a split graph when I use:

```
mutate(color=ifelse(O>mean(O),"green","red")) %>%  ggplot(aes(x=M,y=O,color=color))+geom_line()+scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "darkgreen"))
```

I get the following graph:

[image]

Comment: you need to make a new variable that is e.g. FALSE if below mean and TRUE if above mean. set color to that.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Do not edit the question anymore, if you are changing it. Ask a new question for new objectives. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but makes a break in the line.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  M = 1:5,
  O = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)

df <- mutate(df, above = O > mean(O))
ggplot(df, aes(x=M,y=O, color=above))+geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a variable `color` to mark your color type.

For points use `geom_point()`, not `geom_line()`.

Edit: `color` option splits the data in 2 groups. Use `group=1` (one value for all) to force a single group.

Advice: Avoid naming a variable `O`, there is a big confusion with `0` (zero).

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(M=rnorm(10), O=rnorm(10)) %>% 
  mutate(color=ifelse(O > mean(O), T, F))

#ggplot(df, aes(x=M, y=O, color = color)) + geom_point()
ggplot(df, aes(x=M, y=O, color = color, group=1)) + geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "green"))


# > df
#             M           O color
# 1   0.05829207 -0.03490925 FALSE
# 2  -0.09255111 -0.52513201 FALSE
# 3   0.44859944  0.19371037 FALSE
# 4  -0.54216222  0.40783749  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! i get that i can have 2 different colors that way, but how can i specify which ones?

Comment: Add one of `scale_color_*()` layer. For example: `ggplot(df, aes(x=M, y=O, color = color)) + geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "darkgreen"))`

Comment: See on [docs.ggplot2.org](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html) more details.

Comment: Thank you so much, any idea why those lines look so super weird vertical lines?

Comment: It must be related to your data. With my random values I didn’t see any vertical line. A line between (x, y0) and (x, y1) is vertical.